# New Shallow Well Jet Pump and Bladder Tank Install will not build pressure in tank

Tags: well-pump

I have just installed a new Acquaer SJC110-1 1 HP shallow well jet pump with a new 86 gallon bladder tank for pumping water from a lake at about 10'.  I have not replaced all the lines from the lake, but I did replace the foot valve.  I believe all my new joints are good and leakproof.

When I turn on the pump, it builds pressure to 30 PSI, the cut-in pressure, but will not build to the 50 PSI cut-off and just stays at 30 PSI.  I have tried adjusting the bladder tank pressure and tried to ensure it was at the 28 PSI that I believe is the correct pressure for the bladder.

If I open a valve at the tee, water will flow, but it has a constant sound of trying to push out air (in other words, it chatters, but is flowing).  Once I shut everything off, there is no water in the tank (opening the valve at the bottom of the tank no water flows out) and there seems to be a whoosh of air and then the pressure gauge drops pretty quickly to 0 PSI.

I have ensured that the tank is empty and pump primed before turning on the pump each time.

I am suspecting it is the intake line between the pump and the foot valve, but it's not in an easy place to check.

Any assistance in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The suction side of your piping has a fault and is leaking air. The pump is therefore airbound and unable to build pressure. Repair or replace the suction piping between the pump and the foot valve, re-prime the pump, and it should work.